# Объединить метки [цикл] и [циклы]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить эти метки в пользу [циклы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8b) (у этой метки больше вопросов и есть описание).

Comment: Добавил [голосование за синонимизацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8B/synonyms), пока модераторы спят.

Comment: Модераторы проснулись! =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пока не забанишь, не проснутся

Comment: @alexolut, возможно в этом есть доля правды)